# Discrete Morse Function for $n$-simplex

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, simplex, morse-theory

I am trying to find a "useful" discrete Morse function for the $n$-simplex.

According to (https://www.emis.de/journals/SLC/wpapers/s48forman.pdf page 12), a possible discrete Morse function is $f(\sigma)=\dim\sigma$.

However, this type of discrete Morse function is typically "useless".

Since a $n$-simplex is contractible to a point, I am looking for a discrete Morse function $f$ that reflects this information. That is, we should be able to "collapse" the $n$-simplex to a point according to $f$.

For small $n$, I am able to find such discrete Morse functions. However for general $n$, how do we define $f$ systematically?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you come across Bestvina-Brady Morse theory? It's probably not what your looking for, but is worth a look. (It's a sort of "cubical" morse theory.)