# Simple proof for bound on the sum of Betti numbers for piecewise linear complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, cw-complexes, simplicial-complex, morse-theory

Let a piecewise linear $d$-dimensional complex $M \subset \mathbb{R}^m, m \geq d$  be obtained by attaching $K$ convex $d$-dimensional polytopes $\{ C_i \}_{i=1}^K$ (cells), along their facets without deforming or banding those polytopes. That is:
$$
M = C_1 \cup C_2 \cup C_3 \cup \cdots \cup C_K.
$$
Since each cell $C_i$ is convex, they are topological disks and intersection of any two cells, $C_i\cap C_j$, is also a topological disk.

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to show the following bound on the sum of the [Betti numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betti_number) of $M$:

$$
\sum_{N=0}^d\beta_N(M) \stackrel{?}{\leq} K \tag{*}
$$

Intuitively, it seems to me that the largest possible sum is obtain in case where all cells $\{C_i\}_{i=1}^K$ are not attached to one another, but each is just "floating" in the space, and therefore each $C_i$ contributes a single Homology $\beta_0(C_i)=1,~~ \beta_N(C_i) = 0, N >0 $ to the sum in (*). It seems wasteful to try to attache the cells to introduce higher Homologies, to get loops, holes etc...

My goal is to see **whether this intuition is correct?** Any help or any suggestions, comments will be appreciated.

---

I have only limited familiarity with topology, and was wondering if this is a known fact or easily provable one. I did some literature review and was thinking about two approaches listed below.

---

**First approach.**

After reading the excellent [notes](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/524e/9b92d11b9a318c6a1bf95b001bd452ae90f3.pdf) by Forman on Morse theory on Cell complexes  I was trying to use Corollary 3.7 (The Weak  Morse Inequalities) on page 108:

> **Corollary 3.7** For every $N$
>   $$
> \beta_N(M) < m_N(f).
> $$Where $\beta_N(M)$ is the $N$th Betti number of cell complex $M$ and $m_N(f)$ is the number of critical points of index $N$ of (discrete) Morse function $f$ on $M$.

Since each facet of $M$ can contribute at most one critical point to $f$. This corollary seems to imply the bound:

$$
\sum_{i=0}^d\beta_N(M) \leq \# \{\text{all facets of } M\}
$$
However, this clearly involves a lot of over counting. So was wondering if one can find Morse function $f$ (in a sense of Furman) on $M$ such that on each cell $C_i$ the function has few critical points? To get $\sum_{N=1}^d m_N(f) \leq m K$, for some small $m$, perhaps $m=1$ and show (*), this is somewhat related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3093347/discrete-morse-function-for-n-simplex) math stackexchange question.

**Second approach.**

Alternatively, I was thinking that maybe just application of [Mayer-Vietoris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayer%E2%80%93Vietoris_sequence) can yield $(*)$? But was not able to progress much. Not sure how to use convexity of each cell $C_i$ to get simple MV sequence.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, all what you need is a finite CW complex $X$ with the total number of cells equal to $K$. (Your polyhedral complex would be a very special case.) Let $c_i$ denote the number of $i$-dimensional cells. Then $H_i(X)$ is isomorphic to the cellular $i$-th homology group 
$$
H^{cw}_i(X)= Z^{cw}_i(X)/B^{cw}_i(X).$$
We have: $Z^{cw}_i(X)\cong {\mathbb Z}^{c_i}$, hence, $\beta_i(X)\le c_i$ and, thus,
$$
\sum_{i} \beta_i(X)\le \sum_{i} c_i = K. 
$$
As a reference for CW complexes and cellular homology, see for instance, Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology"

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the equality $\sum_i c_i =K$. I think we have by construction $c_d =K$, but for $i < d$ what is the bound on $c_i$? how can we bound $c_i$, i.e., the number of lower-dimensional cells? For example, if cell $C_i$ is a $d$-simplex, doesn't it also yield a lot of lower-dimensional simplices formed by faces of $C_i$?

Comment: @them: Oh, I see, I misunderstood your definition of $K$, I thought that it the total number of cells used to define $X$. Then my argument does not give the correct inequality.